# Getting into Analog Design/Electronics

Tags: analog

I've worked with the AVR-series of microprocessors before, as well as twiddling around with digital ICs. Recently I've gotten interested in analog design, but I don't understand it very well. I've looked around for resources but most of them assume that you already have prior knowledge. Are there any good ones for beginners?

Comment: I dunno what you mean by "resources", but I'd get a copy of "The art of electronics" (Horowitz & Hill).

Answer (score 2):

['Getting Started in Electronics,' Forrest Mims](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0945053282) - was quite good in my beginning exploration days (if you want to start building around a breadboard).

From a simulation perspective, any intro text bundled with a free SPICE version (or if not, there are several free versions via web search) is a good start.

['PSPICE and circuit Analysis', Keown](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130157953) - good one.

['The SPICE BOOK,' Vladimirescu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471609269) - another (slightly more advanced and covering more broad versions of spice).

Aside from the very classic, Horowitz and Hill mentioned, those are good primers - H&H like Mims, is also very hardware oriented vs. simulation. Depending on your level, I would argue Mims is the gentlest intro.

Comment: No need for a SPICE bundled with a text: LTspice is free and has no limits (unlike the "student edition" SPICEs that often come with texts)

Answer (score 1):

The *Radio Amateur's Handbook* (hopefully the ARRL is still printing it) dates back decades and has excellent sections on introduction to circuit theory and analog and digital (and in the earlier ones, even tube) electronics. It will take you from beginner status all the way through learning about complex radio receivers and high powered transmitters and various modulation methods. And since it's a practical text, it's also full of circuits you can build and test.

It's obviously communication focused, but is an excellent introduction to electronics. I'm a bit biased since I spent a lot of time with it in 10th & 11th grades :-)

The really nice thing about the RAH is that it's carried by just about every library and you don't need the newest, most up to date versions. One from the mid 80's will do just fine. Back then it was about $20; I have no idea what they go for these days.